# UNION doesn't work displaying error when combine with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the data by month so I can use it in my forecast/chart but the UNION doesn't seem to work well when combined with GROUP BY. Hope you can help me solve my problem.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testingfolder");  
    $query4 = "SELECT MONTHNAME(consultationstatus_date) AS MONTH,
                       consultationstatus_diagnosis, 
                       count(*) as number
    FROM tbl_consultationstatus 
    WHERE month(consultationstatus_date)=1
    GROUP BY consultationstatus_diagnosis
    ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
               SELECT MONTHNAME(consultationstatus_date) AS MONTH,
               consultationstatus_diagnosis, 
               count(*) as number
    FROM tbl_consultationstatus 
    WHERE month(consultationstatus_date)=2
    GROUP BY consultationstatus_diagnosis
    ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
    ";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($connect, $query4); 
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))  
    {  
        echo "['".$row["MONTH"]."', '".$row["number"]."','".$row["consultationstatus_diagnosis"]."'],";  
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question add show table description, some insert datas and expected result. We can't help with  `doesn't seem to work well`.

Comment: The problem here is the GROUP BY it doesn’t work well when combine with UNION can’t even echo the data, just need help how to fix the syntax of this

Comment: Did you try wrapping in an outer query ?

Comment: The problem is already solved thanks btw.